# Read verification code automatically and access for Login in App in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I am creating one App and it has verification phone number required functionality which allow user to enter into App. We send sms to the Users through the gateway and we need to read verification code directly from the SMS without typing code into App. But don't know how to read verification code automatic from the SMS and access in my App.I have gone thorugh the searches for this but could not find any path to move ahead. Is it allow in iOS and if Yes, can anyone tell me what to do to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Apple added this feature in iOS 12

just add:

```
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        self.verifyCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    }
```

to your controller and make sure your SMS has "Verification code", "code", "Login code" in it and apple will read those messages and show the last 1 minute received code on top of your keyboard for verifyCodeTextField.

You can check your SMS and there is a line under the number it means apple has detected it in your SMS and you are good to go.

If other people know the keyword in other languages that helps apple to detect the code I would love to know them.

Answer (score 11):

**From iOS 12** it is possible to improve the user experience for native textField (actually anything that implements [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits) to be precise) by:

```
myOTPTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

More information can be found in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)

For the HTML you can achieve it by:

```
<input id="my-one-time-password-textfield" autocomplete="one-time-code"/>
```

More information can be found in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element)

Comment: both `id` and `autocomplete` should be added

Answer (score 3):

Your app can not read directly from the list of SMS messages.  That would be a security risk.

But a couple things you can do would be 1:

allow the user to type in the verification code from the SMS (that seems to be the standard thing for most apps)

2:

use a custom URL scheme such as "myapp://verfication:12345" that when clicked in a SMS, goes straight to your installed app and does the verification. [Here is a tutorial on how to do the Custom URL scheme thing](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael, really appriciating the way you guide me. :)

Comment: you're welcome!  I hope I set you on the right path.  If you have additional questions while you're trying to implement one of these two solutions, feel free to ask additional separate questions here on [so].

Comment: @MichaelDautermann  I also did with custom url and working fine , but what about automatic read verification like many android app automatically access out message app and verified . Please sugest me I have achieve this functionaliy IF we can not do this ios then I have some apple document for same